# Vue JS - Setting Axios action based on variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, axios

I have a Vue component form which sends a *reservation* object to my API in order to store it. I was wondering if I can set the axios action based solely on a variable's value without copying the whole axios function (since both `post` and `put` actions do practically the same):

**(current) Vue component method**

```
sendReservation(action){
    if(action == 'add'){
        axios.post(...);
    } else {
        axios.put(...);
    }
}
```

**(ideal) Vue component method**

```
sendReservation(action){
    let axiosAction = (action == 'add') ? 'post' : 'put';
    axios.axiosAction(...);
}
```

I usually work with AJAX and you can access the `method` property fairly easily, can I do the same with Axios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `axios` object as a function and pass in all the "usual" parameters:

```
sendReservation(action){
    let axiosAction = (action == 'add') ? 'post' : 'put';
    axios({
      method: axiosAction ,
      url: 'someurl',
      data: {
        ...
      }
    });
}
```

See the [Axios API section](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api) in the documentation.

Comment: Wow, I feel kinda dumb now. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: `axiosAction` feels kind of long. Could just simply set the variable name to `method`, and use ES6 shorthand property